# Android Fast Connection/Prototcol

Tags: java, android, sockets, connection

I am searching for a fast connection from an Android Device to a Server. Currently I use SOAP, but is there a way to get a fast connection? I think Sockets are no option cause a permanent connection on a mobile phone will always lost the connection.

Thanks for help!

Regards, Rookee

Comment: *What* do you want to send/receive. The *what* will point you/us to the "best" protocols for the project.

Answer (score 0):

[sockets](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) are not permanent connections.. you can close them when you've finished transmitting..
if sockets are too low level for you, consider [URLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html)

Comment: Currently I justs send simple Commands link "Received Message" or something no realy big Objects or Images...

Comment: a simple `Socket` should do the job for you.. do you have any authentication mechanism in place?, how are your data objects represented? (if it is soap then you have no choice but to continue using soap - to at least construct the SoapEnvelope). you can also use `HttpUrlConnection` to post the soap message (xml) to the server if you need to.